# (node:24) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] em produção apenas

Tags: node.js, react, npm, deploy

Tenho um projeto em reactjs, tudo estava bem até eu fazer meu ultimo deploy, ele até faz o build, mas quando vou ver nos logs:

```
(node:24) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:24) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

Localmente funciona perfeitamente, mas em produção ocorre esse erro.
Já tentei alterar a versão do react-scripts 5.0.1 para outras e nada.
tentei npm install, npm update, npm ci e nada tbm.

Segue meu package.json

```
   {
  "name": "admin-hostel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.1",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^6.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.2.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-babel-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vai na pasta >node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js

substitua :

```js
onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
    // Keep `evalSourceMapMiddleware`
    // middlewares before `redirectServedPath` otherwise will not have any effect
    // This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
    devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));

    if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
    }
},
onAfterSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
    // Redirect to `PUBLIC_URL` or `homepage` from `package.json` if url not match
    devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));

    // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
    // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
    // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
    // it used the same host and port.
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
    devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
},
```

por :

```js
setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
    if (!devServer) {
        throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined')
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
        require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app)
    }

    middlewares.push(
        evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer),
        redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath),
        noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath)
    )

    return middlewares;
},
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: então, mas é só em produção que acontece isso !! vou ter que alterar o 'node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js' em produção ? localmente funciona perfeitamente